# CoreData insert new data, leave existing

Tags: ios, core-data, overwrite

i get data from a web service, that I then store with Core Data.
When I get fresh data from the web service, it contains data that I have already stored.
In Core Data I store the unique ID of each dataset as provided by the web service.
In my current implementation, I just store multiple instances of a set with a unique ID. But I want the existing one to remain, and the new one to be ignored. Or, since they are the same anyway, the new one to overwrite the existing one.
What would be the approach here?

Thanks

Comment: Try and fetch an existing object with the unique id; if you don't get an object, insert a new one.

Comment: Usually, it is better to sync the app with the server. So just update everything that coming from server.

Comment: Please explain what do you want? Would you like to overwrite or not? If you do not want to overwrite then please look at this link implementation  https://github.com/Gagan5278/DemoApps/blob/master/TwitterDemo/TwitterDemo/Model/TwitterUser%2BCoreDataClass.swift  

in this code you can ignore 'checkForObjectCountWithIdentifier' function.  Also try to implement batch saving for better performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to check that a new object which is come from API does exist in the database using uniqID. If yes then overwrite old object to new object if you can't get then insert a new object.

Follow sample code It might help you

```
    //MARK:- get if ClassRoom Exist
    func getClassroom(_ classRooMID:String) -> Classroom? {

        var allClassroom:[Classroom]!
        let request = Classroom.getFetchRequest()
        let keyVal = classRooMID
        request.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "classroomid = %@", argumentArray: [keyVal])
        do {
            allClassroom = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request) as! [Classroom]
        }
        catch let error as NSError{
            // failure
            print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        if allClassroom.count != 0 {
            return allClassroom[0]
        }
        return nil
    }
```

while inserting a new object

```
    //MARK:- InsertClassroom Data
    func insertClassroomData(_ classRoomDict:NSDictionary) -> Classroom {
        let keyValue = classRoomDict[KEY_CLASS_ROOM_ID] as! String
        var classroomObj = self.getClassroom(keyValue)

        if (classroomObj == nil){
            classroomObj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Classroom", into: managedObjectContext) as? Classroom
        }
        classroomObj!.setClassroomFromDict(classRoomDict)

        return classroomObj!
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
class func defaultInsert(data:[String:Any]) -> AppLabels {
    var label = self.fetchLabelFromLabelUsingVarID(var_id: data["var_id"] as! String,screen: data["name"] as! String)
    if label == nil{
        label = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "AppLabels", into: CoreDataStack.managedObjectContext) as? AppLabels
    }
    if data["var_id"] != nil {
        label?.var_id = data["var_id"] as? String
    }
    if data["name"] != nil {
        label?.name = data["name"] as? String
    }
    if data["value"] != nil {
        label?.value = data["value"] as? String
    }
    if data["var_name"] != nil {
        label?.var_name = data["var_name"] as? String
    }

    return label!;
}
 class func fetchLabelFromLabelUsingVarID (var_id:String,screen:String) -> AppLabels? {
    let fetchrequest = NSFetchRequest<AppLabels>(entityName: "AppLabels")
    fetchrequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "var_id == %@ && name == %@", var_id,screen);
    fetchrequest.fetchLimit = 1;
    do {
        let fetchedResults = try CoreDataStack.managedObjectContext.fetch(fetchrequest)
        if let applabel = fetchedResults.first {
            return applabel
        }
    }
    catch{

    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Please add some more detail for your answer only code will not help questioner to solve there issue.